# ADO Large DataSet throws out of memory exception

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I have a huge `dataset` (about 1.5 million records) that throwing a "out of memory exception", the `dataset` appears to load from the database rather quickly (2-3 seconds) but when the Merge() method is called the application crashes and throws a "Out Of Memory" exception.

```
DataSet dsTemp = setupBpc.GetAllData(); << THIS WORKS
if (dsTemp != null)
{
   dsSetupData.Merge(dsTemp); << OOM Exception
}
```

The application is old, I am somewhat stuck with ADO as refactoring would be a massive undertaking. It's a `winforms` application using `Janus GridEX` and I've not been able to find any sort of way to do paging with a `GridEX` component.

But the thing that stumps me is this doesn't appear to be an issue with the `dataset` itself, it's retrieving from the database and loading without issue. There seems to be something with the Merge() method that is causing this to fail.

Comment: Simple solution: Make it a 64 bit application. Solved. Otherwise - well, there is need to refactoring. At least reduce the merge size (load the data in smaller sizes, merge them one by one). Now is the time you pay - someone created a hugh technical debt using an inadequate technology that NEVER was considered acceptable by anyone outside of MS and tutorials.

Comment: That is a different question - and a VERY BASIC .NET question. Hint: it is a compiler switch / project setting. But personally I would start fixing the codebase. Someone did a crappy job designing this - and throwing memory into that type of problem regularly is not the way to do things. For example, there is ZERO need to load 1.5 million rows to start with. This is just ridiculous crappy UI design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might run out of memory since you are merging data and even more memory is required. Think about it: First you hold the original DataSet, then you merge, which is basically copying the original dataset into the new one. Thus taking twice as much memory.

I am sure Janus GridEX supports paging parametering for data retrieval, and you should implement this through the whole data layer. I think this code change is unavoidable since this doesn't scale, and you have been lucky to not have this issue earlier!